# Angular2 - canActivate not getting value from AuthService

Tags: authentication, angular

Trying to make Login feature using angular-2 where I have used one login component, authservice, logingard with canActive.

While following example from angular2 document, I don't get value of loggedin in guard file and it asks every time for login

Posting sample code here
AuthService

```
export class AuthService {
  loggedIn: boolean = false;

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  } 

  login(credentials) {
    let user = JSON.stringify(credentials);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post(this._apiUrl, user, options)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .map((res) => {                     
                    this.loggedIn = true;
                  }
                  return res;
                });
  }}
```

Loggedin Guard

```
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _auth: AuthService, private _router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    //Get problem here. Everytime this comes false
    if(this._auth.isLoggedIn()) { return true; }

    this._router.navigate(['login']);
  }
}
```

login component

```
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private userService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  onSubmit(email, password) {
    this.userService.login(email, password).subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Btw, following example of
https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/angular-2-authentication-revisited-611bf7373bf9#.723a4ssji
without localstorage

Comment: I dont see implemntation of isLoggedIn() function in AuthService?

Comment: When and where is `login(credentials)` being called? I think you should use an observable for `loggedIn` otherwise `canActivate` doesn't wait for the `_http.post()` to complete.

Comment: I guess this requires a Plunker to reproduce.